# What does warning `client_input_hostkeys: received duplicated ssh-ed25519 host key` mean?

Tags: ssh-keys, scp

When I use `scp` to copy some files from a server, I've lately been getting the following warning:

```
$ scp -rC myserver.com:~/test.log .
client_input_hostkeys: received duplicated ssh-ed25519 host key
```

I tried googling what this means and how to fix it but couldn't figure anything out.

This is the `scp` command I use for reference:

I get the error on MacOS 12 with both `fish` and `bash` shells.

I have a parallel `ssh` session running to the same server, could that be why I'm getting the error?

The following files are in my `.ssh` directory:

```
~/.ssh 
❯ ls 
config      id_rsa      id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Comment: ever figure this out? I'm suddenly getting this same message when I rsync, although it's an ssh-rsa key not ssh-ed25519.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have the server configured to have 2 keys that have the same public key. This most likely means that on the server side, the server ssh config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has 2 entries for the same type of key at the same path or with duplicate contents, eg.

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```